# CentOS 7 RAID 1 and virtual machines

Tags: centos, raid, software-raid, raid1, libvirt

A CentOS 7 host OS will have three CentOS 7 virtual machines running inside it.  Libvirt will be used to set up the virtual machines.  Both the host OS and each of the three virtual machines will need to be configured for RAID 1.

**How do I plan the hard drives for the four CentOS installations?**  (1 host and 3 VMs.)  Can the RAID be done on only two physical hard drives?  One hard drive for the primary storage, and the other hard drive for the redundant storage?  With 4 partitions on each of the hard drives, one partition each for the host OS and the three virtual machine OSs?  So that each CentOS installation would have one partition on the first hard drive for primary storage and a second partition on the second hard drive for RAID 1 backup?

**I have viewed instructions for setting up RAID in CentOS 7, but what I am asking here is can I do it with only two hard drives as described above?**  Buying 8 physical hard drives (2 for each of the 4 CentOS installations) would be much more expensive.

Comment: I assume you think of software RAID. As that is usually based on partitions, not whole disks (see e.g. [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-raid-config.html#fig-raid-manual-part-bootready-add), your approach would be possible. But youl'd have to use raw disks (partitions) for your virtual machines; is there any reason not to use virtual disks for the VMs?

Comment: @ridgy My main concern is that the backup needs to be on a separate physical drive than the primary storage.  Beyond that, I am not concerned about whether the VMs are on partitions or virtual drives.  However, I would like for the creation process to be simple enough that I could move towards scripting the whole thing after a couple of practice run throughs.

Comment: @ridgy Your link above is to CentOS 5 documentation.  This OP is about CentOS 7.  **Can you please point to the RAID documentation for CentOS 7?**  The RHEL 7 SysAdmin Guide does not seem to have anything about RAID in it.

Comment: There seems to be no newer (official) CentOS documentation than CentOS5. The RHEL 7 documentation is [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-raid.html). As RedHat focusses on _ btrfs_, there won't be much changes in md documentation anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about RAID1,'primary' and 'backup' are not proper terms, as both disks are just 'mirrors' of each other and thus exchangeable.

When you have RAID1 on two disks in your host, you have the mirroring for all data in the filesystem, so for virtual disks as well, as they are just files. If this is enough (protects your data against failure of *one* disk), it is sufficient to create *one* virtual disk for each VM, as it is protected by the RAID1 of the host. If for any reason you want to have 'virtual' RAID1 for the VMs, just give two virtual disks to each (maybe you want to work with RAID in the VMs for educational reasons, or you are sort of paranoid).

Having four partitions on each disk in four different RAID devices does not give you additional protection against disk failure, as when one disk fails all four RAID devices are degraded.

Let's be specific: With two disks (sda and sdb) having four partitions each (sda1...sda4, sdb1...sdb4) and creating four RAID mirrors (md1=sda1+sdb1, ..., md4=sda4+sdb4), if e.g. sdb fails, each mirror loses one device, which means it is still working but degraded. If both disks fail you lose your data. This is the same as if you had just one partition each (sda1, sdb1) for one mirror (md1) and virtual disks on that for your VMs: One disk failure = md1 degraded, two disks failed: data lost.

And if you have the chance of using more than two disks, you better think of a different RAID level or using `zfs` with RAIDZ2 or RAIDZ3. All depends on how failsafe yoursystem should be.

Comment: You say `Having four partitions on each disk in four different RAID devices does not give you additional protection against disk failure, as when one disk fails all four RAID devices are degraded.`  **Why do you believe that having the two sets of mirrors separated into two separate physical hard drives will NOT protect against disk failure?**

Comment: Edited my answer to be more specific.